# `gcloud source repos clone` with service account is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Deploying my personal project to GCE(Google Compute Engine), I tried to clone a git repo in Google Cloud Platform. But it did not work. I guess git repo in GCP uses code.google.com internally, and that is not compatible with service accounts. It prints

```
Cloning into '/home/...'...
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your generated googlecode.com password; see https://code.google.com/hosting/settings
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/.../r/...', '/home/...', '--config', 'credential.helper="gcloud.sh"']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

Currently logged in `...-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` and image is Debian (GCE default)

Answer (score 1):

How was your GCE instance created?

You need to make sure it has https://www.googleapis.com/auth/source.full_control scope. To list scopes you can run

```
gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE_NAME \
    --zone=INSTANCE_ZON --format="yaml(serviceAccounts)"
```

If you used [gcloud command to create the instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--scopes) you can use `--scopes` flag to include the source scope.

Alternatively if you use [developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) to create the GCE instance make sure to select "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" in  "Service account" section.