# How to clone a private git repository using a initialization shell script

Tags: git, shell, bitbucket, google-compute-engine

I'm start working with google compute engine and trying to automate the VM initialization process. On startup the VM should clone a private git repo on bitbucket and run the aplication.

So, if it was a public repo would look like this:

```
git init myapp
cd myapp
git pull https://me@bitbucket.org/me/myapp.git
```

How do I do if I want to keep my code private?
Should I download a SSH Key first? If so, how do I do this?

I also tried cloning it to the cloud repository, but also asking for credentials. Is this a better aproach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the Google Repository docs I found that you can get access to the project repository on google cloud using a helper from the Google Cloud SDK running the command line:

```
git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
```

But as the SDK is already installed in all GCE instances, so just:

```
git init myapp
cd myapp
git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
git pull https://source.developers.google.com/p/<project-id>/r/default
```

if cloning into a local machine, just install the [SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/)

Comment: All these steps are packaged into single gcloud command: `gcloud source repos clone default`. Also for new projects you might need to create repos as `default` might not exits by default. When you create GCE instance you might want to allow access to all APIs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067253/gcloud-source-repos-clone-with-service-account-is-not-working